# Android Kotlin: Local Notifications not showing

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a simple app created in **Android Studio** with **Kotlin** (`minimumSDK: API 24, Android 7.0 Nougat`).

I'm trying to send a local notification when the user open my app. For this I import the following code in **AndroidManifests.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <application... />
</application>

</manifest>
```

And in **MainActivity.kt** I have the following code:

```
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat

import com.example.notificacoesvls.R

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        createNotificationChannel()
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        
        var builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "104")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setContentTitle("My Frist Notification")
            .setContentText("This is the description of notification...")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)

        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
            // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
            notify(45, builder.build())
        }
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val name = getString(R.string.channel_name)
            val descriptionText = getString(R.string.channel_description)
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            val channel = NotificationChannel("104", name, importance).apply {
                description = descriptionText
            }
            // Register the channel with the system
            val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
                getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see, I'm creating a Channel in **onCreate**, and try to show the notification when my app show my frist screen (by **onStart** method).

I try to run this app in emulator with `Pixel 6 Pro API 34`, and my physical device `Galaxy S21` (Android 13), and I don't receive any notifications, What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get notification permission for Android13+. Your code seems fine. Downgrade your emulator api and compileSdk at gradle(app) to 31  to check the situation.
[Check offical documentation here.](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission)